# How to set Theano flags in the THEANORC file? And where?

Tags: installation, compiler-flags, theano

I'm trying to install Theano, but it is more complicated than I thought. I've used Enthought Canopy and the guide on http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/install.html#install. In order to complete the installation I want to set the flags mentioned in the installation guide:

> (Needed only for Theano 0.6rc3 or earlier) Set the Theano flags
>   blas.ldflags=-LC:\Users\\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.0.0.1160.win-x86_64\Scripts
>   -lmk2_core -lmk2_intel_thread -lmk2_rt.

According to http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/config.html I should do that by creating a .theanorc file on $HOME/.theanorc:$HOME/.theanorc.txt. However, I don't know how to translate $HOME into a normal windows path - what is $HOME if I have a default installation using Enthought Canopy?

Comment: (... or you use virtualbox to make an ubuntu vm :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find your home on windows, you can click the "start" button, then select your username on the right column. This will open a window in the right folder.

On Windows 7, this corredpond to this path: C:\Users\YOUR_USER_NAME